# Asynchronous file reading to increase perf

Tags: go, goroutine

**Probleme :** I'm working on a script to parse a `bitcoin block` (binary file).
My script is working fine, now I would like to increase the performance (I mean make it faster) and parse multiple blocks in the same time.
To do so I thought of using goroutines in order to read multiple files in parallel.

**First question :** Does using goroutines to to read / parse multiple files in parallel will reduce the execution time ?
Maybe `goroutines` are not the solution ?

**Seconde question :** If yes, what's wrong with the follow code which take the same time as the synchronious version to parse let's say 100 blocks ?

```
func getBlock(path string, ch chan s.Block) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    utils.Handle(err)
    defer f.Close()

    s.NewBlock(f, ch)
}

func main() {
    nbr_blk := len(os.Args) - 1
    files := os.Args[1:len(os.Args)]

    var t timer.Timer
    t.Start()

    ch := make(chan s.Block)

    for _, file := range files {
        go getBlock(file, ch)
    }

    for i := 0; i < nbr_blk; i++ {
        select {
        case blk := <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("Blk prev hash : %x\n", blk.Header.Hash_prev_block)
        }
    }

    time_spent := t.Stop()
    fmt.Printf("Time spent to parse %v blocks : %v\n", nbr_blk, time_spent)
}
```

block.go :

```
func NewBlock(f *os.File, ch chan Block) {
    var blk Block
    blk.From(f)
    ch <- blk
}
```

`blk.From(f)` is just reading the file and "populating" the `struct Block` with bytes

Comment: It depends on what's taking time. If you're IO-limited, running more IO concurrently won't make the disk any faster, and could make it slower due to queuing and seeking.

Comment: It not about hardware (almost sure) as I can improve time with a bash script `for f in ~./blocks/blk*.dat; do ./bitcoin-parser  $f & done
` => 10x faster to read 26 blocks